# symfony - credentials problem

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to fully understand how the credentials/permissions system works in symfony(1.4)

I have 2 groups and 2 users.

User 1 has the following permissions:
`Add.Car, Delete.Car`

User 2 has the following permissions:
`Add.Bike, Delete.Bike`

Now what I want to do, is only allow users with the `Add.x` permissions to be able to add to a category table.

The problem is, that If I have:

`credentials: [Add.Car, Add.Bike]` - it seems to look for users with BOTH of these, not either of them.

Is this how the credentials work and If so, is there a way to check if the user has either `Add.Bike` **OR** `Add.Car` before allowing them to create new records?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the credentials in [ ]

```
credentials: [[Add.Car, Add.Bike]]
```

see http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/13 'Complex Credentials' section

Comment: Excellent. I knew I'd seen how to do it somewhere!

Comment: Perhaps here [Symfony Docu](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_sub_complex_credentials) :-)